# python search for a date in a range of 2 dates

Tags: python

i am using two table
if the date 'r_date' in the first table is in the range [date_from, date_to] and the quantity 'num_days' is in the range [days_from, days_to]. it is necessary to insert a column into the first table values*koeff

df

| r_date | num_days | product | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-05-13 | 3 | CARD | 11.0 |
| 2018-06-09 | 9 | CARD | 67.3 |
| 2018-06-09 | 12 | AUTO | 11.0 |

res_df

| date_from | date_to | days_from | days_to | koeff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-05-11 | 2018-06-12 | 3 | 12 | 6.8714 |
| 2018-06-12 | 2018-06-25 | 2 | 8 | 5.7825 |

**answer**
if the r_date is in the range and num_days is in the range, add a new column new_value where if the conditions are met then new_value = koeff*value if not then we leave old value

df

| r_date | num_days | product | value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-05-13 | 3 | CARD | 11.0 | 11*6.8714 |
| 2018-06-09 | 9 | CARD | 67.3 | 67.3 |
| 2018-06-09 | 12 | AUTO | 11.0 | 11.0 |

I made it

```
def test_lst(lst1, lst2):
    for index, i in lst1.iterrows():
        for index, n in lst2.iterrows():
            print (i['date_from'] <= n['rep_date'] <= i['date_to'] and i['days_from'] <= n['num_days'] <= i['days_to'])
```

Comment: Pleas include your expected output.

Comment: Please check the indentation of your code in your question after my edit is the way it is supposed to be. Indentation is important in python, so you need to check that your code shows up correctly after you've asked your question. Use [code fences](/help/formatting) by adding three backticks on the lines before and after your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try with [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
#convert columns to datetime if needed
df["r_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["r_date"])
res_df["date_from"] = pd.to_datetime(res_df["date_from"])
res_df["date_to"] = pd.to_datetime(res_df["date_to"])

merged = pd.merge_asof(df, res_df, left_on="r_date", right_on="date_from")

df["adjusted"] = merged["value"].mul(merged["koeff"]).where((merged["r_date"].between(merged["date_from"], merged["date_to"]))&
                                                            (merged["num_days"].between(merged["days_from"], merged["days_to"])),
                                                            merged["value"])

>>> df
      r_date  num_days product  value   adjusted
0 2018-05-13         3    CARD   11.0   11.00000
1 2018-06-09         9    CARD   67.3  462.44522
2 2018-06-09        12    AUTO   11.0   75.58540
```